# Open Contact List at Specific Contact

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook

I have an iPhone app that uses a `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to pick out a contact. First time you select a contact, the contact list obviously starts at the top, under the letter 'A'. However, say you selected a contact under 'M'; if you then later want to change which contact is selected, I want to initialise the contact list so that it's already scrolled to the 'M' section.

Here's the code I use to open the contact list:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
                    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
                    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;                    
                    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
                    [picker release];
```

I can't find any information in the reference guide on how to configure the scroll offset where the controller opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is unavailable in `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`. However you can implement a custom `UITableViewController` which does that using the `AddressBook` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [ABAddressBook]

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i );
    NSString* name = [(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what this code is supposed to do - is this intended as an expansion of Deepak's answer?

Comment: no this code iterate over all all contact in iphone address book so you can get the data using Copy Value and property id.

Comment: Right... I'm not sure how that relates to the question, I'm afraid?